# installing matlab unexpected error "Task MATLAB R2015b Startup Accelerator for C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b does not exis"

Tags: matlab, installation

When I'm installing Matlab this error exists. After checking all of the products that will be installed, an unexpected error has occurred and doesn't enter the installation progress. I try to remove the old folder installation, this error still occurred. I try to change folder installation to download folder, this error still exists.

````
(Agu 22, 2021 10:17:22) java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.install.ComponentSizeAggregator.add(ComponentSizeAggregator.java:13)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.downloadProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:102)
    at com.mathworks.install.ProductInstallerImpl.installProducts(ProductInstallerImpl.java:62)
    at com.mathworks.install.InstallerImpl.install(InstallerImpl.java:108)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.InstallTask.execute(InstallTask.java:46)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractBackgroundTask.execute(AbstractBackgroundTask.java:38)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:73)
    at com.mathworks.installwizard.model.AbstractTask.call(AbstractTask.java:23)
    at com.mathworks.wizard.worker.WorkerImpl.doInBackground(WorkerImpl.java:24)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

(Agu 22, 2021 10:17:22) Error: The application encountered an unexpected error and needs to close.  You may want to try re-installing your product(s).  More information can be found at C:\Users\asus-pc\AppData\Local\Temp\mathworks_asus-pc.log
(Agu 22, 2021 10:17:29) Exiting with status -1
(Agu 22, 2021 10:17:29) End - Unsuccessful.```
````

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: For installation problems, your best bet is to contact MathWorks directly.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer (Agu 22, 2021 10:17:22) Task MATLAB R2015b Startup Accelerator for C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b does not exist
(Agu 22, 2021 10:17:22) java.lang.NullPoi ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. However, my installer has some errors. Thus, I downloaded it again and it worked.